# How to build, package and deploy a react-native-web app in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, cicd, software-engineering

Given there is a [react-native-web solution](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web), what needs to be done to build it and run inside a Docker container?

- What is the build environment/toolchain?
- Which environment is required to run?

From what I can find so far, it's not clear how this should work.

UPDATE: [Project examples](https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-native-web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty general question, I will try to answer the best I can:
If you want to just build and run an image:
Build the project: npx expo-cli init react_native_app --npm

1. You need to create a [Dockerfile](https://www.rockyourcode.com/how-to-run-react-native-expo-web-in-a-docker-container/) file in your repository
2. Docker build -t {tag_name} . (You can replace '.' eith the Dockerfile path)
3. Docker run...
4. If you want you can create docker compose file to better control your app.
   Reference:
   https://www.rockyourcode.com/how-to-run-react-native-expo-web-in-a-docker-container/

Comment: hi there @Avi! welcome to our community! Which dependencies be included in the Dockerfile - say Ubuntu based? Do I have to use expo? I've also added project examples.

Comment: This base image FROM node:14.13.1-buster-slim is debian based image.

Comment: the complete Dockerfile featured in the linked blog article is not trivial for nodejs newbies, but is essential to get a hello world app running in the container. Anyway, it works! thx